# Algorithm to find bijection between arrays

Tags: algorithm, wolfram-mathematica, bijection

I have two arrays, say `A={1, 2, 3}` and `B={2, 4, 8}` (array item count and numbers may vary). How do I find a bijection between the arrays.

In this case, it would be `f:A->B; f(x)=2^(x)`

Comment: Homework by any chance??

Comment: There's clearly no general method to do this, unless there are extra constraints. Are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have remarked, this problem is ill-defined.

Other possible functions that give the same results are (among probably infinite others): (8 x)/3 - x^2 + x^3/3, x + (37 x^2)/18 - (4 x^3)/3 + (5 x^4)/18, and (259 x^3)/54 - (31 x^4)/9 + (35 x^5)/54.

I found these solutions using:

```
n = 5; (* try various other values *)
A = {1, 2, 3} ; B = {2, 4, 8}
eqs = Table[
  Sum[a[i] x[[1]]^i, {i, n}] == x[[2]], {x, {A, B}\[Transpose]}]
sol = Solve[eqs, Table[a[i], {i, n}], Reals]
Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, n}] /. sol
```

Sometimes not all of the a[i]'s are fully determined and you may come up with values of your own.

[tip: better not use variables starting with a capital letter in Mathematica so as not to get into conflict with reserved words]

Comment: Probably (I guess) the title should be `Find ONE bijection ...` in which case any interpolation could do

Comment: I need an algorythm, and not one specific solution, sori if my question was not clear.

Comment: @martynas the code above in the blue code block can be considered as an algorithm to find some rules that connect the two series. Varying n provides various solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this problem has a general solution. You may try [FindSequenceFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html), but it will not always find the solution. For the case at hand, you'd need a bit longer lists:

```
In[250]:= FindSequenceFunction[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 8}}], n]

Out[250]= FindSequenceFunction[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}}, n]
```

but

```
In[251]:= FindSequenceFunction[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 8, 16}}], n]

Out[251]= 2^n
```

You can also play with `FindFit`, if you have some guesses about the bijection:

```
In[252]:= FindFit[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 8}}], p*q^x, {p, q}, x]

Out[252]= {p -> 1., q -> 2.}
```

Comment: Is there algorithm available online of this function? I need to make and application.

Comment: @Martynas Unfortunately, I don't know what algorithm is used in `FindSequenceFunction`. Hopefully, more knowledgable people here will remark on that.

Comment: yeah, those are good, but there is fact, that I need to write my own application :) its the assignment ;]

Comment: @Leonid Look what this guy is doing : http://www.rowan.edu/colleges/las/departments/math/facultystaff/nguyen/talks/Data%20Mining%20OEIS%20Math%20Dept%20Colloquium%20Feb%202011%20PDF.pdf

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for the link, looks very interesting. I wonder to what extent this indeed can be automated. But in any case, Mathematica is definitely the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tag Mathematica, I'll use Mathematica functions as a reference.

If you are interested in an arbitrary fit of your data with a smooth function, you can use Interpolation.  E.g.

```
a = {1, 2, 3}; b = {2, 4, 8};
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{a, b}]];

(* Graph the interpolation function *)
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 3}], Graphics[Point /@ Transpose[{a, b}]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 9}}, Frame -> Automatic, Axes -> None]
```

[image: Plot of f]

Interpolation uses piecewise polynomials.  You can do the same in your favorite programming language if you happen know or are willing to learn a bit about numerical methods, especially B-Splines.

If instead you know something about your data, e.g. that it is of the form c d^x, then you can do a minimization to find the unknowns (c and d in this case).  If your data is in fact generated from the form c d^x, then the fit will be fairly, otherwise it's the error is minimized in the least-squares sense.  So for your data:

```
FindFit[Transpose[{a, b}], c d^x, {c, d}, {x}]
```

reports:

```
{c -> 1., d -> 2.}
```

Indicating that your function is 2^x, just as you knew all along.

Comment: +1. It probably doesn't matter too much in your example, but it was pointed out to me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610265/how-to-plot-a-gene-graph-for-a-dna-sequence-say-atgccgctgcgc/5644442#5644442) by Mark McClure that since version 6 you can use `Point@Transpose[{a, b}]`  (rather than `Point /@ Transpose[{a, b}]`), and this syntax is much more efficient. You may already be aware of this. (I wasn't, until Mark pointed it out)