# Plotting vectors based on a genetic sequence

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence call it `ACGTCCT...`.  Is there anyway of plotting this without using stairs? Does anyone know how to make the colourful 2D/3D arrows towards the bottom of the page this: [How to plot a gene graph for a DNA sequence say ATGCCGCTGCGC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610265/how-to-plot-a-gene-graph-for-a-dna-sequence-say-atgccgctgcgc)

in matlab?  Other suggestions on the `ACGTCCT` visualisation are welcome too.

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'stairs'?

Comment: @Andrey I believe he means the latter structure of DNA. What do you hope to be able to see better with a nontraditional representation?

Comment: Stairs as in `stairs(X,Y,'-rs','linewidth',1)`.  My sequence is not actually from DNA but a Markov chain showing the movements of a person during a 15 minute period.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`arrow.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278) submission from FileExchange is what you need. It's hard to imagine that it's not built in, but at least this contribution fills the gap nicely. Here is an example using it like in that Q/A you linked to:

```
function randomWalk(seq)

n = length(seq);

ptStart = zeros(n, 3);
ptEnd   = zeros(n, 3);

cols = jet(n);

for i=1:n
    switch seq(i)
        case 'A'
            d = [1 0];
        case 'T'
            d = [-1 0];
        case 'G'
            d = [0 1];
        case 'C'
            d = [0 -1];
    end

    ptEnd(i,:) = ptStart(i,:) + [d 1];
    ptStart(i+1,:) = ptEnd(i,:);
end

rng = [min([ptStart; ptEnd], [], 1); max([ptStart; ptEnd], [], 1)];
axis(rng(:))
for i=1:n
    arrow(ptStart(i,:), ptEnd(i,:), 'BaseAngle', 90,...
                                    'TipAngle',  15,...
                                    'Length',    30,...
                                    'CrossDir', [1 1 0],...
                                    'EdgeColor', cols(i,:),...
                                    'FaceColor', cols(i,:));
end

axis equal
view([45 15])
```

```
>> randomWalk('ATGCGTCGTAACGT')
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful!  Just what I was hoping for.  Been looking for this for ages!  Thanks and big thumbs up!

Comment: @user1134241 Great, glad it's working! `arrow.m` is one of my favs.